# Where can I find Bluetooth Received folder?

Tags: bluetooth

I am able to setup a link with another laptop (Win 7) and even able to send files (surprisingly around 3-4 MBps). But I am not able to locate where exactly the files are getting stored in my Ubuntu 12.04. Is there anyway where I can setup the default folders for it.

Answer (score 17):

They are in /home/username/Public (in Ubuntu 13.04).

Comment: for me it is in /home/username/Public ( in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS )

Comment: for me it is in /home/username/Téléchargements ( in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS FR)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, at least in my lapto, it's in ~/.cache/obexd

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu 14.04:

If you configure Bluetooth file transfer using the "Personal file sharing" settings (`gnome-file-share-properties`), your files will be located at your Downloads folder.

[image]

Comment: after that, it said the file was received, but I couldnt find it anywhere. After a find, it was placed at "~/.cache/obexd" at 16.04, whatamess..

Comment: For me it is in ~/.cache/obexd as well, even after making the modifications suggested in this thread. How the hell are we expected to know to look there lol.

Answer (score 3):

Yes search for "Personal File Sharing Preferences" in Applications from the Dash.

You'll get a menu of options and you can change Downloads as the primary folder to which files are bluetoothed to.

Answer (score 3):

You can open a terminal and do:

```
find ~ -name *filename or part of it*
```

~ means it'll search from /home, -name because you want to find a filename.

If you don't sudo you'll get a few permission denied (find couldn't access in read to check for filename) but that doesn't matter.

For me (using blueman on Ubuntu 18) they ended up in `/home/anonymous/.cache/obexd/20200130_223605.jpg`

Not sure who's the genius who thought this would be a good default....

Answer (score 1):

Normally files are saved in your /Home Folder check it out.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in /home/Public but if you already installed "Blueman applet" on you system, you can easily change the folder using its "Local Services" option

Answer (score 0):

Any version of ubuntu just select File System in explorer and search public folder see your transferred files there then select make link and shift to desktop

Answer (score 0):

To find Bluetooth inbox files, just type the name of the file you sent to your Linux computer in the terminal / command line like this:
`find ~ -type f -name "nameOfTheFile.txt"`

You should be able to see something like this.
`./.cache/obexd/nameofthefile.txt`

This is the location where Bluetooth files are landing on Kali/Debian Linux, so from explorer just type in the following target.
`~/.cache/obexd/`

If you don´t like this location, change it by right clicking on the Bluetooth icon and going to Local Services>Transfer>Incoming Folder and changing it to the desired location.

Comment: Searching for exact file name might be misleading. I just noticed, that an image sent from mobile phone was renamed to some random letters, even without extension.