# Where are bluetooth received files saved

Tags: files, bluetooth, transfer

I have used **Blueman** and the default Bluetooth manager an every time I accept the file transfer from the Phone to the PC, it shows that it is transferring and even notifies me that the transfer was successful but I can not find the image anywhere.

Where are files stored after sending them via Bluetooth to the PC?

I already checked my Home folder. The Picture folder which I thought it would be the one for images. Then the document folder and afterwards I did a huge check on all folders under `/home`. No luck. Is nowhere. I even checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211662/where-can-i-find-bluetooth-received-folder?rq=1) with no luck.

Comment: Did you check the `Downloads` directory?

Comment: I find them in ~/Desktop.

Comment: Nope not there. Maybe I should just go and see the code. Save me the time.

Comment: For 17.04, see [Ubuntu 17.04 Sending/Receiving files by Bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/a/951660/4512).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found my BT transferred files in Home>Public

Answer (score 11):

**Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04**

All the transferred files through bluetooth are stored in `~/Downloads` directory.

Comment: Thanks Abby for sharing. Have not tested yet on 13.10.

Comment: This is also the case for 15.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 also uses this directory.

Comment: for Kubuntu 16.04 they are also landing in `~/Downloads`

Answer (score 1):

I came here to see where my files ended up but none of the answers hit the point, so for completeness: I am using blueman-manager with xfce on trusty and the files ended up in my home directory.

Comment: I am running a `find` for more than 30min to find the file, thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Mine ended up in `~/.cache/obexd/` In Xubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't find mine anywhere (used find ~/ -name '2015*.jpg' -ls and it comes back with zilch).

It's a major defect that the BT applet doesn't let you configure where they get saved. Right now it looks like they go into the æther...

[edited] Grrr yes it does...once you find it under "Local Services" FFS, and you still have to enable it to receive. This really ought to work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 the path is set in Bluetooth Settings.

[image]