# Ubuntu 17.04 Sending/Receiving files by Bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04, transfer

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my computer and I am a new Linux user.

I activated my Bluetooth and tried to send some pictures from my phone (after connecting the device to the laptop) but it failed.

I tried then sending a picture from my laptop to my phone and it didn't do anything.

I changed the Share Settings and activated the Bluetooth sharing as it is said in the documentation but...

What to do? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the terminal, run (as normal user)

```
systemctl --user start obex
```

That worked for me… as it enabled me to send – for example – files to my phone via bluetooth.

For a fix that works accross reboots, run (as normal user)

```
systemctl --user enable obex
```

Which creates an according symlink. This is a set-and-forget thing, enabling file transfers permanently so you don't need to start obex every time.

Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1645631

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After banging my head against a selection of walls, I came across a post somewhere which recommended running the command

`/usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd`

as your own user in a terminal. That seems to have done it for me. Didn't require installation of blueman, obex-ftp, etc.

I now added that command to my 'start-up application' list and the sun keeps on shining..

Comment: So did the solution work for you too? If it did, maybe you want to vote for it by pressing that ^ button on the left :-)