# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I want to send files from my phone to my Laptop and vice versa through Bluetooth. But the Bluetooth on my system doesn't work. When I turn on the Bluetooth switch in *System Settings > Bluetooth*, nothing happens and also the visibility switch on the right hand side is always disabled.

Output of `rfkill list` is as follows:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `dmesg | grep Blue` is as follows:

```
[   29.519992] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   29.520012] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   29.520016] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   29.520019] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   29.520025] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   54.305795] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   54.305799] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   54.305804] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I don't know if the drivers were installed or not and I don't know how to check it either.

Any idea what the issue is?

---

**Update**:

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` is as follows:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName:  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c342 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: To check if bluetooth packages are installed, I suggest you to install Synaptic Package Manager and look for bluetooth on it.  BTW we could file a bug report, as I'm suffering this too, in my case I have two bluetooth icons in the system panel, and making my PC visible from both doesn't makes it really visible.  It also fails to find other bluetooth devices.

Comment: Search the bug reports for bluetooth RT3290 and you will find some.  I really doubt it is fixed even now

Comment: @Jeremy31 You are right Jeremy. It seems it was an issue even with the older versions.

Comment: I think some arch Linux users had it working up until kernel 4.0

Comment: @Jeremy31 Something usable on Ubuntu?

Comment: this worked for me https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/919542/how-can-i-make-my-bluetooth-works-on-ubuntu-16-04/959060#959060 The bluetooth pile is largely outdated on 16.04

Comment: Might sound cliche but I found turning my computer on and off again as a fix. I am using 18.04

Answer (score 45):

My ubuntu 16.04 couldn't find the Bluetooth devices, even though the devices's pairing switch was on.

[Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth Speakers](https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2016/04/30/ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-speakers/)

In short, I tried following process.

1. `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. Change `#AutoEnable=false` to `AutoEnable=true` (at the bottom of the file, by default)
3. `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`

Then, my Ubuntu machine was able to find the Bluetooth devices!

Comment: apos thats not correct , it should be systemctl restart bluetooth.service

Comment: This worked for me with the change that @Amias mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: The best way is actually `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: working even if still not perfect, thx! I think there may have conflict with other bluetooth manager here.., this may help too https://askubuntu.com/a/680192/46437

Comment: I am getting an error for the third command.  Failed to restart etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount: Unit etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount not found.

Answer (score 37):

After so many attempts to solve this issue the following commands did it for me.

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Then I do the following

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked for me too.

Comment: I really need to remember this...

Comment: Worked on 18.04!!

Comment: Worked on 19.10

Comment: Didn't work on 20.04. I even tried `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` & `sudo bluetoothctl`

Comment: Good heavens Ubuntu is an absolute joke when it comes to Bluetooth. This worked for me (temporarily) until it breaks itself again.

Answer (score 25):

I tried all the above but it didn't work for me, as the bt is not blocked but disabled and can't be turned on.

but i found this

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

and i got my disabled bluetooth come to life and pair with my headphones!

Comment: Thanks it worked on latest version

Comment: Thanks! This is the only thing that helped (didn't try reboot though).

Comment: yes! also worked for ubuntu 18

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Comment: Best solution so far, works.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 8):

My Bluetooth tended to "fall out", and I had to to do a reebot. But this solved it:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

(easier than a reboot!)

Comment: Wouldn't [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/808114/225694) be a more permanent solution? Restarting the service every time while likely functional seems to me a less attractive choice.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case I think it was a bug of my old installed version of unity control center, or some missing dependencies. Resolved easily updating unity-control-center:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Hope it may help.

Comment: Ah no, it only says "headphone connected" but no sound came out of it.

Answer (score 4):

For me after two days of searching without any luck. 
I burned an image of Ubuntu on a USB stick, entered Try mode.
Tested Bluetooth and it works and could find devices and pair.

Then I installed a new image of ubuntu on my HardDisk tried to install all of programs installed on old installation till that point when I found that Bluetooth stop working

I figured that I installed a tool called **TLP** for power management, When I removed it via `apt remove tlp` and reboot, Bluetooth worked and could find other devices!

Maybe TLP needs to be configured someway to work good with Bluetooth

I hope this may help you

***Update:***

I've installed the latest version of TLP and now Bluetooth working without any problems.

<s>TLP releases on Gihub: [here](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/releases)</s>

Download the latest release uncompress

```
cd TLP-1.0
# use checkinstall so that you can remove it anytime
sudo checkinstall
```

Use PPA to get latest release

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp
```

And reboot.

Comment: Your answer is inappropriate in several ways: 1. You don't know if  TLP is installed (not default for most Ubuntu flavours). 2. Instead of uninstalling completely, use the [solution from the FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#btusb). 3. Please don't suggest installing from source, use the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp). 4. There is no difference between TLP 0.8 ... 1.0 with respect to your problem. I reckon checkinstall didn't work as expected and TLP is disfunctional now. Good luck with removing the wreckage --- Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much! I completely forgot I installed TLP and it caused me a lot of issues.

Comment: it worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$ rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So from the list Bluetooth is blocked by rfkill, no wonder I cannot connect in the GUI.

```
$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
$ rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

After the unblock command I get a new device hci0 that is Soft blocked, but the hp-bluetooth device is unblocked and it doesn’t work from the GUI still.

```
$ hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Operation not permitted (1)
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
[sudo] password for karibe: 
Can't init device hci0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill (132)
rfkill unblock bluetooth hci0
rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

After this everything is working as expected. I do not know why rfkill is from time to time blocking bluetooth, but now I know how to unblock when I need to use it, and block when I don’t need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I always use this this to restart everything:

```
:~# rfkill block bluetooth; rfkill list; /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart;\
/etc/init.d/bluetooth status;\
modprobe -r btusb; modprobe btusb;\
/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart; /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
```

Comment: What do I do after that? Do I restart the computer? Also, I seem to be getting error messages from it: http://imgur.com/a/h5hO8 (the output scrolled past the window end, so I took two screenshots.)

Answer (score 1):

After some time with Bluetooth upload from phone not working on my laptop, I found that installing `blueman-applet` (`sudo apt install blueman`) and adding 'trust' for the device and then specifying to accept uploaded files fixed my problem. I don't really know why there are two Bluetooth icons in my taskbar now -- but the blueman-applet seems to provide a lot more options than the standard Gnome/Ubuntu applet.

The extra applet menu:

[image: applet menu]

Context menu of the Devices list allows 'trust' of device:

[image: trust device]

Local Services dialog allows Bluetooth to accept uploaded files:

[image: accept files]

---

**EDIT**: further digging shows that there is a 'Personal File Sharing' dialog recommended by Ubuntu that is *supposed to* support this functionality directly without `blueman-applet`. But it didn't work for me.

[image: personal file sharing]

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer is for Debian only!

In my case the Bluetooth device was not detected. In my case it was part of the Qualcomm Atheros hardware:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [103c:217f]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Installing the proprietary/non-free firmware and rebooting helped.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install firmware-atheros
```

Comment: This is a Debian answer. There is no `firmware-atheros` package in Ubuntu.

Comment: I got "Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "firmware-atheros" "

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't realise that Ubuntu does not have that package.