# How can I make my bluetooth works on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, lenovo

Even if I turn on my bluetooth in the settings, I can't see any devices. Please help me :)

Laptop : Lenovo ThinkPad E570
I got the Intel Wireless AC-8265 for my bluetooth.

Thanks :)

edit :

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

edit 2 :

```
[    3.501077] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.501110] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.501118] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.501122] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.501136] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.518325] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38       2015
[    3.519185] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.519187] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.519187] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.519188] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.519188] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.519190] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.520068] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.897682] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38   2015
[    3.898687] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.898688] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.898688] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.898689] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.898690] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.898690] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.898702] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    5.314755] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.314755] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.314758] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

edit 3:

```
cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | egrep -v "^#|^$"
[General]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: done, please help me :)

Comment: @soarezzz Please add the output of these commands to your question `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | egrep -v "^#|^$"` and `dmesg | grep Blue`

Comment: @ali done, please help me ;)

Comment: @soarezzz Please add `AutoEnable=true` to your `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file and then restart. I hope that work for you.

Comment: @soarezzz  and then run this command `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: @ali i tried everything you told me .... no good results

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade kernel and linux firmwares.

- Upgrade your kernel to version at least 4.8
- Then you can download a snapshot of linux firmware, for example https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-1dcf7691f623c24762976e2debe05248d627e814.tar.gz

`sudo mv /lib/firmware /lib/firmware.old
 sudo tar xvfz linux-firmware-1dcf7691f623c24762976e2debe05248d627e814.tar.gz
 sudo mv linux-firmware-1dcf7691f623c24762976e2debe05248d627e814 /lib/firmware`

Then download the package source of bluez 5.46 :

`wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.46.orig.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.46-0ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.46-0ubuntu3.dsc
sudo dpkg-source -x bluez_5.46-0ubuntu3.dsc`

Install build dependencies.

`sudo apt build-dep bluez
sudo apt install devscripts
cd bluez-5.46`

Build the packages.

`sudo debuild -b -uc -us
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i bluetooth_5.46-0ubuntu3_all.deb \
bluez_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
bluez-cups_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
bluez-hcidump_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
bluez-obexd_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
bluez-tests_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
libbluetooth3_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
libbluetooth3-dbg_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
libbluetooth-dev_5.46-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo reboot`

You should then be good to go.