# Bluetooth not working after update

Tags: bluetooth

I'm very new to ubuntu and slowly getting my head around it but i seem to regularly have issues with bluetooth connection. It's been working well until I completed a suggested update and now I cannot connect to a bluetooth speaker.

I've run `sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
 ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-01-11 23:33:41 GMT; 13min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 4236 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─4236 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
bluetoothd[4236]: Not enough free handles to
bluetoothd[4236]: Sap driver initialization 
bluetoothd[4236]: sap-server: Operation not 
bluetoothd[4236]: Endpoint registered: sende
bluetoothd[4236]: Endpoint registered: sende
bluetoothd[4236]: connect error: Permission 
bluetoothd[4236]: connect error: Too many le
bluetoothd[4236]: connect error: Permission 
bluetoothd[4236]: GLib: Source ID 158 was no
bluetoothd[4236]: connect error: Permission 
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

Any idea what to do? The Sap driver or RFCOMM server seems to be an issue, what are those? Apologies still very new to linux

Comment: check this, it might help
https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: Same for me. Updated 16.04 and now Bluetooth does not works at all

Comment: Same for me too. Updated today 16.04 and now bluetooth problems (disconnection after about 1 minute).

Comment: @Henry Yes that's the same as mine. I tried uninstalling bluez and reinstalling and its seems to have made it worse

Comment: @Darayd I think they have messed something up in the Ubuntu update of 2-3 days ago. If this is the case, I really hope they correct the bug and provide an update on Monday !

Comment: Also waiting for fixes.

Comment: After a few official updates the issue was solved.