# Bluetooth not working on Dell Latitude E7470 with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, 17.10, bluetooth, adapter

I have no Bluetooth connectivity (No adapters found) on Dell Latitude E7470 with Ubuntu 17.10.

[image: bluetooth settings]

I read some related questions, which has helped me.

- [Ubuntu 17.10 not detecting bluetooth mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966734/ubuntu-17-10-not-detecting-bluetooth-mouse/966931#966931)
- [Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)
- [Bluetooth not working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994958/bluetooth-not-working-after-update)

```
$ rfkill list all
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

but if I check Bluetooth status, it shows like

```
$ sudo service bluetooth status 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-03-02 17:09:12 IST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 4649 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 772.0K
      CPU: 33ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─4649 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 02 17:09:12 home-pc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 02 17:09:12 home-pc bluetoothd[4649]: Bluetooth daemon 5.46
Mar 02 17:09:12 home-pc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 02 17:09:12 home-pc bluetoothd[4649]: Starting SDP server
Mar 02 17:09:12 home-pc bluetoothd[4649]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2513 Dell Computer Corp. internal USB Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2513 Dell Computer Corp. internal USB Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5686 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ dmesg | grep Blu:
[    2.975668] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.975681] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.975683] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.975684] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.975689] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.999152] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.999153] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.999154] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.999165] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.999166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.999166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.999187] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.999196] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    2.999196] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.999197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.999197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.801701] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.801703] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.801706] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm':
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM [8086:156f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I219-LM [1028:06dc]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0250]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2513 Dell Computer Corp. internal USB Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2513 Dell Computer Corp. internal USB Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5686 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.109491] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.880544] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    2.975668] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.975681] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.975683] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.975684] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.975689] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.999152] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.999153] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.999154] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.999165] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.999166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.999166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.999187] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.999196] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    2.999196] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.999197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.999197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.069439] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.069547] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.074130] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.801701] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.801703] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.801706] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

How can I get it working?