# Bluetooth stopped working suddenly on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

My bluetooth has been working without any issue for several months and today it just stopped working.

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since pon 2019-12-23 20:07:18 CET; 2min 43s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1488 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 2.7M
      CPU: 7ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1488 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Error adding Link Loss service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Not enough free handles to register service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Not enough free handles to register service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Not enough free handles to register service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Current Time Service could not be registered
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Not enough free handles to register service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Not enough free handles to register service
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: Sap driver initialization failed.
gru 23 20:07:18 Home bluetoothd[1488]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

dmesg

```
dmesg | grep bluetooth
[    5.440959] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd failed with error -2
```

Why has it stopped workign and how do I fix this? What's going on?
I cannot pair any device.

I have already tried reinstalling bluetooth and bluez and pulseaudio but it didn;t solve it. Additionally, when I now click on the system settings cog icon to access system settings, nothing happens.

Comment: [Could you try steps on this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: None of the suggested answers seem to be relevant to reported problem, they did not fix it.