# Ubuntu 18.04 - Bluetooth not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and my laptop is not scanning other devices. All the devices I am trying to connect are fully functional and working with other devices and platforms.

I tried the following:

> $ bluetoothctl

And this is what I get:

```
[NEW] Controller 34:23:87:DC:89:A8 Linux [default]
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 34:23:87:DC:89:A8 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 34:23:87:DC:89:A8 Linux [default]
[bluetooth]# devices
[bluetooth]# exit
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller 34:23:87:DC:89:A8 Linux [default]
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/1043219/1053060
2. https://askubuntu.com/a/808114/1053060

UPDATE:
Output of `sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-17 22:36:42 PKT; 8min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 729 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4545)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─729 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 17 22:36:42 Linux systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 17 22:36:42 Linux bluetoothd[729]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Mar 17 22:36:42 Linux systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 17 22:36:42 Linux bluetoothd[729]: Starting SDP server
Mar 17 22:36:42 Linux bluetoothd[729]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Mar 17 22:37:10 Linux bluetoothd[729]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Mar 17 22:37:10 Linux bluetoothd[729]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that Ubuntu is missing bluetooth drivers.

Folow these steps:

1. Download [driver](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases).
2. Install the package.

```
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/broadcom-bt-firmware-10.1.0.1115.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/broadcom-bt-firmware-10.1.0.1115.deb
```

> Note: Make sure to use the correct path.

3. Reboot.