# Dell XPS 13 9365 can't activate bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, firmware

All efforts to switch on bluetooth are failed. No any traces of bluetooth adapter could be found:

`lsusb` produces:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58c8 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0091 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7552 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` shows following:

```
[    5.881993] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.882010] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.882014] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.882016] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.882019] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.943529] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    7.943598] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[   11.072476] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.072478] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.072481] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Intel 8265 driver installed, but has no effect.

Any guru could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue. Just installed Pop!_OS (ubuntu based) on my Dell XPS 13 9365. Ran across this solution which worked for me.

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Found it on here: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/808114#808114|solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/808114#808114%7Csolution)

*I also have both wifi and bluetooth checked in the wireless switch section in BIOS (bluetooth was initially unchecked). Doubt it is relevant but I made this change in BIOS before trying out the solution.*

Hope it helps.